# Changing images depending on device orientation

Tags: css, image, cordova, orientation, media-queries

I'm building a basic web App using PhoneGap for a local company. I have created two images for the header/banner at the top of the App. One is optimised for portrait orientation and one is optimised for landscape.
I want to be able to show either one depending which way the device is held. I have been reading about media queries and frankly its a little bit over complicated for my needs, as JQuery mobile will take care of rest of the functionality for me, and I'm only using one CSS for the whole App.

Does anyone have a few simple lines of code I can add to help solve this issue?

Answer (score 8):

You can use CSS media queries for portrait and landscape orientations, it is not complicated at all:

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) { ... }
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

Using these media queries you can override `background-image` for any orientation.

Official documentation: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation

There are two ways of using it:

Presume you have `<div>` with class `header`:

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait)
{
    div.header { background-image:url(image1.jpg); }
}
@media screen and (orientation: landscape)
{
    div.header { background-image:url(image2.jpg); }
}
```

Alternatively, you may wish to use `<img>` tags. In this case you will need two of them, and hide/show only one with CSS rules. Let's say, `<img>` tags have classes `header-land` and `header-portrait` respectively:

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait)
{
    .header-land { display:none; }
    .header-portrait { display:inline-block; }
}
@media screen and (orientation: landscape)
{
    .header-land { display:inline-block; }
    .header-portrait { display:none; }
}
```

Comment: So just say I have 2 images image1.jpg and image2.jpg, how do I use the above code with these files?

Comment: This may cause some problems:
At an nexus 7, if the keyboards shows, the screen changes from portrait to landscape

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer about how to use media query, it's a quite easy way to solve the issue. But one prerequisite is that it's ok to show the images as css backgrounds, and not as `<img ... />`

Pseudo code

```
.my-banner {
  ...declarations like:
  background-position: 
  border: 
  margin: 
  padding: 
}
@media all and (max-width: 320px) {
  .my-banner {
  background-image: url(portrait.png);
}
@media all and (min-width: 321px) {
  .my-banner {
  background-image: url(landscape.png);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, so how do i call these images from my HTML?

Comment: Min and max width doesn't precisely determine orientation. Also, 320px is true only for iPhone's screen.

Comment: @keaukraine Yes, it may be better to use landscape and portrait for orientation.

Comment: @user1942412 Add these declarations into your css file. Upload the images and point the path to them. In my example I assume the css file and images are in the same folder. If you for example have the images in outside, in an other folder: `images/portrait.png`and `images/     landscape.png`

...you use this path `background-image: url(images/landscape.png);`
Will this help you? Note that @keaukraine also gives a good example how to solve the issue if you choose to include the images with `<img ... />`